# Sci-Fi story about cooking being the pinnacle of human culture

Tags: story-identification, food

I remember a SciFi story, probably from the 60s or 70s, about a human culture that only eats dishes made of mushroom paste. The core planet has extremely refined taste. One day, someone comes back from a trip and immediately participates in the planet-wide cooking challenge. To the surprise of everybody he wins, only for them to discover that he used real garlic instead of the mushroom paste. In the end, he is expunged from the planet.

What's the title and author of the story?

Comment: Do you remember how long this story is?

Comment: Well, @Andrew already answered my question before I could get back to yours. ;-)

Comment: Our [duplicate closure policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/) is that if an answer identifies the same work they are dupes regardless of the content of the question

Comment: Duplicates aren't a bad thing, it's not a mark against you. It's only a way to keep (esp story-id) questions linked to each other. Some might remember details similar to the linked question, others might remember similar details as you have. Linking them as duplicates allows both parties to find the correct answer and have all that info in one spot

Comment: Oops. Okay, you convinced me. Thank you, @fez for the clarification!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asimov's [Good Taste](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Taste)

> **Chawker Minor returns from his 'Grand Tour', including a visit to
> Earth,** to his home on Gammer, one of several artificial satellites
> orbiting the Moon. The introverted society of Gammer specialises in
> artificial computer-designed food flavourings much in demand on Earth,
> to the point of shunning "natural" food grown in "dirt", and Chawker
> is inspired to enter the annual competition for flavouring, using
> something new and radical.
>
> Despite the disapproval of his parents and elder brother, Chawker
> Minor does design a new flavouring that wins the competition. Asked by
> the Grand Master, who can taste and analyse flavourings to the
> smallest detail, to explain his successful and intriguing entry, he
> reveals that he has not used artificial computer-designed molecules,
> but an **actual raw ingredient, garlic, maintaining that no assemblage
> of molecules may duplicate the complexity of a living organism.**
> The Grand Master, and all Gammer society, are revolted by this breach of good taste. **Chawker Minor is disavowed by all and exiled from his home.**

Comment: Yessir! I'm flabbergasted as to how quick the answer came up. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndreasHäusler I imagine there are a large number of scifi.se regulars that knew the answer as soon as they read "real garlic" in your question, it's a classic

Comment: Absolutely- once the garlic was mentioned it was just a matter of who could type faster

Comment: Once garlic was mentioned, it was just a matter of taste. _FTFY, @Andrew :)_

Comment: With this answer accepted, the question is a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/209233/short-story-by-isaac-asimov-about-a-mental-chef

Comment: Anyone interested in Answer speeds may find this of interest. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13196/statistics-on-answer-speeds

Comment: Thank you for that